# How to do this query in MySQL which one should I use using left join or right join or inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

```
table book:
BookCode| AuthorShortN  |Title
============================================
101 | Anton B   | THe Book of Leaves
102 | JJ. Abram | Wish Upon A Star
103 | Anonymous | Secret of Universe
104 | Anton B   | The Sentinel


table author:
AuthorID|AuthorFullName   |Nationality
=====================================
A01 | Anton Balwin    | USA
J02 | Johannes J Abram| UK


table bookauthor:
BookCode|AuthorID
=================
101 | A01
102 | J02
103 | X01
104 | A01
```

I have three table with the structure look like this. And I would like to have a query such that the result will be:

if I do this query

```
select * 
from book tb , author ta, bookauthor tba 
where tb.BookCode = tba.BookCode and tba.AuthorID = ta.AuthorID
```

It will not show `row 103   | Anonymous | Secret of Universe` as the Author is not in the table author.

and what I want is:

```
BookCode| Title         | AuthorID | AuthorShortN
===========================================================
101     | THe Book of Leaves|A01       | Anton Balwin    
102     | Wish Upon A Star  |J02       | Johannes J Abram
103     | Secret of Universe|NULL      | Anonymous
104     | The Sentinel  |A01       | Anton Balwin
```

how to fix the query to produce such result ?

Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a left join on the table you allow nulls in:

```
SELECT tb.BookCode, tb.Title, ta.AuthorID, tb.AuthorShortN 
FROM book AS tb
INNER JOIN bookauthor AS tba ON tba.BookCode=tb.BookCode
LEFT JOIN author AS ta ON tba.AuthorID=ta.AuthorID
```

Note your example correct output looks for a null in AuthorShortN and you actually have Anonymous in the data. The inner join to BookAuthor assumes there are entries in this table even when the author is unknown, as it looks in your data.

Comment: my apologies and thanks for pointing that out, it's a typo the AuthorShortN for `103` should be `Anonymous` instead of NULL

Comment: `INNER JOIN` == `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

[Left Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) will give all results from left table whether or not there are corresponding entries in the right table

```
SELECT *
FROM book tb
LEFT JOIN author ta ON tb.BookCode = ta.AuthorID
LEFT JOIN bookauthor tba ON ta.AuthorID = tba.BookCode;
```

Also, Off topic of the question - shouldn't the AuthorShortN field be in the author table?

Comment: The table is correct, because a much more detailed info about the author will be in the `tbl author` whereas in `tbl book` only contain the `Short Name`. Anyway thanks for looking into it..